# Not able to customize font of paragraph in droidtext (Android)

Tags: android, android-droidtext

**Here is Code which I am using...**

```
 Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am generating my first PDF using DroidText");
 Font paraFont =  new Font(Font.COURIER,20.0f,Color.GREEN);
 p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
 p1.setFont(font1);
 doc.add(p1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this helped me to resolve my problem..

```
Font paraFont =  new Font(Font.COURIER,20.0f,Color.GREEN);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am generating my first PDF using DroidText",paraFont);
doc.add(p1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy Solution:

```
private static Font fontbold16 = FontFactory.getFont("COURIER", 16, Font.BOLDITALIC, Color.GRAY);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am generating my first PDF using DroidText");
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.add(p1, fontbold16);
```

> Note: you can change "`COURIER`"  to change `Time New Roman`, `Arial`..etc